Freely homotopic maps of spheres into a simplicial complex of the same dimension
Suppose $X$ is a connected $n$-dimensional simplicial complex and $A,B\subseteq X$ are disjoint, connected subcomplexes. Suppose $f:S^n\to A$ and $g:S^n\to B$ are non-null-homotopic maps. Is it possible that $f$ and $g$ are freely homotopic?
The answer seems to be no when $n=1$ and $X$ is a graph but I'm less confident about the higher dimensional cases.

Do you know that $\pi_3(S^2)$ is nontrivial?

Hints:

For $n=1$ this is indeed true and follows from the algebraic fact that in a free product $G*H$ no nontrivial element of $G$ is conjugate to an element of $H$.

For $n\ge 3$ this is false, take $X=S^2\times [0,1]$, and $A=S^2\times 0$, $B=S^2\times 1$.

For $n=2$ this is true: Use Hurewicz and Mayer-Vietoris.



Hurewicz may not be applicable for $n=2$. But you should be able to appeal to the universal cover.

@JeremyBrazas: of course, I expect that OP knows this trick.
